# ListView doesn't populate with paged ObjectDataSource

Tags: asp.net, listview, gridview, objectdatasource

I'm trying to convert a `GridView` to a `ListView` to allow me more control over the table display.

The `GridView` works fine as defined here and correctly displays data.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvService" runat="server"
    AllowPaging="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID"
    DataSourceID="objService">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ServiceType" HeaderText="Type" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When I convert this to a `ListView`, no HTML is rendered to the page at all. I've even placed them side by side, the `GridView` works but the `ListView` doesn't display.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvService" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="objService">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("ID") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("ServiceType") %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("ID") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("ServiceType") %></td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Here is the `ObjectDataSource`

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objService" runat="server"
    EnablePaging="true"
    TypeName="My.Data.DataSource.ServiceDataSource" DataObjectTypeName="My.Data.Service.ServiceSearch"
    SelectMethod="Search"
    SelectCountMethod="SearchCount">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbSearch" Name="Search" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I feel like I'm missing something basic here. Any idea on why `GridView` populates but `ListView` doesn't?

Am I required to manually *DataBind()* the control in the code behind?

Comment: Show your Select Method of the ObjectDataSource

Comment: Please post all of the code for `My.Data.Service.ServiceSearch` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here seems to be with ListView. Since you have set `EnablePaging="true"` for ObjectDataSource, So your `ObjectDataSource` will always look for a `Select` method having  two parameters: `MaximumRows` &   `startRowIndex`.

`startRowIndex` is incremented automatically depending on your `MaximumRows` setting.

In case of Grid view `MaximumRows` is specified using the GridView property: `PageSize`. In case you don't specify this, default value of `10` is used for `MaximumRows` .

In case of your `ListView` there is NO such setting as `PageSize`, so NO option of any default value. If you check your `Select` method when list view binding is to be done, you will see that the value of `MaximumRows` equals `-1`.

So, the correction you need to apply is using a DataPager in your .aspx file as below. Note that the `PagedControlID`  property is set to ID of your List view.

```
<asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvService"
        PageSize="20">
        <Fields>
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True"
                ShowLastPageButton="True" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>
```

Again , the `PageSize` property specifies the `MaximumRows` parameter value.

Comment: This sounds like it may be the fix. I won't be able to access the code until later on today, but will let you know how it goes.